# ionic2: How to move href tag from view page to Actionsheet (controller)

Tags: ionic2

I am using ionic2 to implement my mobile app.

I used ion-item-sliding for my list items to allow multiple functionalities.

In my view, I have html tags in each of my items as below:

```
...
<a ion-button href="tel:{{item.Phone}}">Office</a>
<a ion-button [href]="sanitize('sms:' + item.cellPhone)">Mobile</a>
<a ion-button href="tel:{{item.cellPhone}}">Text</a>
```

In order to save more space, I would like to move some of my tags into an ionic2 ActionSheet as below:

```
<button ion-button color="danger" (click)="presentActionSheet(item.altPhone)">
                        <ion-icon name="phone-portrait"></ion-icon>
                        Mobile
                        </button>
```

Here is the code in my component class (ts file):

```
presentActionSheet(number) {
        let actionSheet = this.actionSheetCtrl.create({
        title: 'Do you want to?',
        buttons: [
            {
            text: 'Make phone call',
            role: 'destructive',
            handler: () => {
                this.call(number);
            }
            },{
            text: 'Send message',
            handler: () => {
                //this.sendSMS(number);
                window.open(this.sanitize('sms:'+number), '_blank'); 
                return false;
            }
            },{
            text: 'Cancel',
            role: 'cancel',
            handler: () => {
                console.log('Cancel clicked');
            }
            }
        ]
        });
        actionSheet.present();
    }
```

However, when I tap on Send message (to open default sms app), I got "Load Error" on a blank page. 
I have been trying many different ways to move my href tag to the backend controller.

Could anyone please help?  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after two days of researching. I found my answer:

just change window,open to:

```
window.location.href = "sms:" + number;
```

if you want to also attach text message use:

```
window.location.href = "sms:" + number + "&body=Hello from George!";
```

enjoy!